# Limiting barline length on one-line staff?

Tags: lilypond

In the below example, is there any way to prevent the barline from sticking out over the 1 line staff?

```
\version "2.24.2"

\new PianoStaff { <<
        \new Staff \with {
                \remove Time_signature_engraver
                \hide Clef
        } {
              \override Staff.StaffSymbol.line-positions = #'(5)
              \stopStaff \override Staff.StaffSymbol.line-count = #1 \startStaff
              s1
        }
        \new Staff {
                c'1
        }
>> }

\layout {
        \context {
              \PianoStaff
              \alterBroken transparent #'(#t) SystemStartBrace
        }
}
```

[image: barline over 1-line staff pic]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wrong site!   https://music.stackexchange.com

Comment: This questions is for a music engraving software called lilypond which is more like programming than anything musical—I've posted questions about it here in the past. But I'll post it on the music page as well, thank you!

Comment: hi @nat !  Yes, just so you know the music. site has a huge number of lilypond questions, and basically all the world's leading lilypond users (and I think some of the makers of lilypond) are on that site!  enjoy